# Clean fasta file header

Tags: awk

I have a large fasta file with header like this

```
>sample_1 M04839:239:000000000-BVKC2:1:1105:7523:23617;size=450
```

My desired output is

```
>sample_1;size=450
```

How can i do change that ?

Comment: Hi David, since you work with fasta files, you might be interested in having a look at [bioawk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk). It is tuned for fasta files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[ :;]' '{print $1,$NF}' OFS=";"  Input_file
>sample_1;size=450
```